# nativescript angular animation with states never works

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to get animations to work in a ng nativescript app.
Here is how I configured the animation in the component

```
animations: [
    trigger('accessState', [
      state('loggingIn', style({ "color" : "red" })),
      state('signingUp', style({ "color" : "blue" })),
      transition('loggingIn <=> signingUp', [animate('600ms ease-out')])
    ])
  ]
```

Plain and simple: two states and just `color`property change between when transitioning.
In the xml I use the animations as follows:

```
<Label text="hey there buddy" [@accessState]="isLoggingIn ? 'loggingIn' : 'signingUp' "></Label>
```

In my component I than have a method that toggles the value of `isLoggingIn`. The label however always stays green (because of a style defined in a css sheet) and it seems that the trigger never gets called. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nativescript Animations Module must imported and included in the module.

```
import { NativeScriptAnimationsModule } from "nativescript-angular/animations"
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Any demo code for this? I just cannot seem to get this working :(

Comment: @DennyBeulen What in particular is not working? Maybe ask on SO,share your code and I'll try to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test yet, but should work:

```
   <label text="hey there buddy" [@accessState]="isLoggingIn"></label>
   <button (click)="changeState('loggingIn')">log up</button>
   <button (click)="changeState('signingUp')">sign up</button>
```

in the class:

```
...
isLoggingIn="reset";
....
changeState(state){
   this.isLoggingIn="reset";
   setTimeout(() => { this.isLoggingIn = state;},300);
}
```